# Is C++ move constructor obsolete?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I wrote my own string type (`Str`) to demonstrate the basic constructors, destructors and assignment operators; and, I can see them all execute in C++17 except the move constructor.

Apparently, the move constructor is not used much anymore because of Return Value Optimization (RVO).

Is the move constructor only called in response to explicitly calling `std::move`?

When else might it be called?
Is it mostly obsolete because of RVO?

Here's my `Str` type:

```
struct Str {
  Str(): p(nullptr) {}
  Str(const char* s) { cout << "cvctor \"" << s << "\"\n"; copy(s); }
  Str(const Str& s): p(nullptr) { cout << "cpctor deep\""<<s.p<<"\"\n"; copy(s.p); }
  Str( Str&& s) { cout << "mvctr shallow \"" << s.p << "\"\n"; p = s.p; s.p=nullptr; }
  const Str& operator=(const Str& s) { cout << "op=\""<<s.p<<"\"\n"; copy(s.p); return *this; }
  const Str& operator=( Str&& s) { cout << "op= shallow \""<<s.p<<"\"\n"; p=s.p; s.p=nullptr; return *this; }
  ~Str(){ if ( p != nullptr ) { cout << "dtor \"" << p << "\"\n"; delete [] p; } }

private:
  char* p = nullptr;
  char* copy(const char* s)
};
```

Comment: Try `push_back` a few times on `std::vector<Str>`

Comment: What @Nemo said, except then add `noexcept` to your move constructor and then try the vector test again.

Comment: Interesting! Why does noexcept make such a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No not at all

Return value optimization is not the only point where the move constructor is used. Every time you want to construct a value of some type from an `rvalue` is a point where the move constructor is used.

You basically ask two questions in one. Let's start with

> Is the move constructor only called in response to explicitly calling std::move?

The move constructor and `std::move` are tangentially related but in essence very separate. The move constructor is called every time you initialize a variable from an `rvalue` of the same type. On the other hand `std::move` makes it possible to explicitly get from a so-called `lvalue` to such an `rvalue` but it is not the only way.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& value) { // A so-called universal reference
    T other_value = std::forward<T>(value);
}
foo( string{"some string"} ); // other_value is move initialized
```

You see, `std::forward` is another way to obtain an `rvalue`. Actually, `"some string"` also results in an `rvalue` in the above code, of type `const char*`.

---

Time for an intermezzo. If you hear `rvalue` you might be tempted to think about `&&` which is an `rvalue-reference`. This is subtly different. The problem is that giving a name to anything makes it an `lvalue`. So the following code:

```
foo(string&& value) {
    T other_value = value;
}
foo( "some_string" ); // other_value is STILL copy initialized

foo(string&& value) {
    T other_value = std::move(value);
}
foo( "some_string" ); // other_value is now properly move initialized
```

The correct way to think about `&&` is that such a reference can be initialized with an `rvalue` but it is itself not always such an `rvalue`. For more information see also [here](/q/28483250/)

---

> Is it mostly obsolete because of RVO?

Two notable examples where the move constructor is prominently often used besides RVO come to mind

- moving into method arguments

  ```
  void foo(string value);
  // Somewhere else
  string& some_string = get_me_a_string();
  foo( ::std::move(some_string) ); // Uses move constructor to initialize value
  some_string.clear(); // Most probably a no-op
                      // Doing this leaves an empty some_string
  ```

  Note that in the example above, the fact that `some_string` is a reference does not matter whether move construction is used. It is a reference to make it clear that RVO might not always be possible. In this case, after `some_string` has been moved from, will be left in an unspecified, but valid state which is a fancy way to say that no undefined behaviour will occur and the reference is still valid.
- moving into fields

  ```
  class FooBar {
      string fooField;
      //Constructor
      FooBar( string bar )
      : fooField( ::std::move(bar) ) // Uses move constructor to initialize fooField
      { }
  }
  ```

Comment: the question was about implicit calls to `std::move`

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov I think you mean implicit calls to move constructors? There's no such thing as implicit calls to `std::move`.

Comment: Ah hah! Multiple conditional return statements will foil RVO and trigger a move constructor call as explained here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/RVO_V_S_std_move?lang=en